# Activex Control is not loading and working on IE 8 and Ie 9

Tags: activex

I am using activeX control in my website for stationery creation .

If I access my website with "localhost:port/*" then activeX control works fine but if I try to use it with ip i.e. "192.168.1.3:port/*" then , it did nothing.

I am unable to understand is that network issue or IE9 and IE8 compatibility issue or problem with Win7 .

I am working on LAN .

Same code is working fine on WinXp having IE6.

Could anyone please please tell me what the hell is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the URL of the site that you are using is listed under trusted sites, and under 'Custom Level' settings for trusted sites, Select 'Enable ' for 'Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting'.